# Hints on bulk loading 3.6 billion rows to InnoDB on Aurora MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, bulk-insert, aws-aurora, amazon-rds-aurora

everyone!

I'm struggling for a week to bulk load 3.6 billion rows to an InnoDB table on Aurora MySQL 5.6.10a. This table has one FK to a "Main" table and has 12 columns. The first 1.4 billion were loaded overnight, but right now my insert rate is dropping quiklly.

I **disabled** `unique_check` and `foreign_keys_check` but let `autocommit` **on**.

I splited the file into 506 files with around 3.84GB each (7,000,000 rows each) and I'm using `LOAD DATA FROM S3` to load them to the table.

Any hints to improve this task?

Thank you very much!

**Additional details**

All other tables in my SCHEMA use InnoDB as Engine and it works fine since they are much smaller than this one. Is it a good idea to change only this table to MyISAM? What would be the implications of doing so?

My Files are ordered by PK and the PK is an `AUTO_INCREMENT BIGINT`.

```
CREATE TABLE `Movement` (
   `idMovement` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `idLawSuit` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   `content` mediumtext NOT NULL,
   `movementDate` datetime NOT NULL,
   `captureDate` datetime NOT NULL,
   `isReportContent` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   `isDocument` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   `contentInS3` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   `contentS3Url` text,
   `uniqueConcatId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `captureOrder` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `movementExtraInfo` text,
   PRIMARY KEY (`idMovement`),
   KEY `idLawSuit10` (`idLawSuit`),
   CONSTRAINT `idLawSuit10` FOREIGN KEY (`idLawSuit`) REFERENCES `LawSuit` (`idLawSuit`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1470000001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

These are my InnoDB parameters:

```
innodb_adaptive_flushing    ON
innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm    10
innodb_adaptive_hash_index  OFF
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay 150000
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size 8388608
innodb_api_bk_commit_interval   5
innodb_api_disable_rowlock  OFF
innodb_api_enable_binlog    OFF
innodb_api_enable_mdl   OFF
innodb_api_trx_level    0
innodb_aurora_enable_auto_akp   OFF
innodb_autoextend_increment 64
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode    2
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct 100
innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    8
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size 96223625216
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   25
innodb_change_buffering none
innodb_checksum_algorithm   none
innodb_checksums    OFF
innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled    OFF
innodb_commit_concurrency   0
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct    5
innodb_compression_level    6
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max  50
innodb_concurrency_tickets  5000
innodb_data_file_path   ibdata1:12M:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir    
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache  OFF
innodb_doublewrite  OFF
innodb_fast_shutdown    1
innodb_file_format  Antelope
innodb_file_format_check    ON
innodb_file_format_max  Antelope
innodb_file_per_table   ON
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  1
innodb_flush_method O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_neighbors  1
innodb_flushing_avg_loops   30
innodb_force_load_corrupted OFF
innodb_force_recovery   0
innodb_ft_aux_table 
innodb_ft_cache_size    8000000
innodb_ft_enable_diag_print OFF
innodb_ft_enable_stopword   ON
innodb_ft_max_token_size    84
innodb_ft_min_token_size    3
innodb_ft_num_word_optimize 2000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit    2000000000
innodb_ft_server_stopword_table 
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree   2
innodb_ft_total_cache_size  640000000
innodb_ft_user_stopword_table   
innodb_io_capacity  200
innodb_io_capacity_max  2000
innodb_large_prefix OFF
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    50
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF
innodb_log_buffer_size  8388608
innodb_log_file_size    50331648
innodb_log_files_in_group   2
innodb_log_group_home_dir   ./
innodb_lru_scan_depth   1024
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct  75
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm  0
innodb_max_purge_lag    0
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay  0
innodb_mirrored_log_groups  1
innodb_monitor_disable  
innodb_monitor_enable   
innodb_monitor_reset    
innodb_monitor_reset_all    
innodb_old_blocks_pct   37
innodb_old_blocks_time  1000
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size    134217728
innodb_open_files   6000
innodb_optimize_fulltext_only   OFF
innodb_page_size    16384
innodb_print_all_deadlocks  OFF
innodb_purge_batch_size 900
innodb_purge_threads    3
innodb_random_read_ahead    OFF
innodb_read_ahead_threshold 56
innodb_read_io_threads  32
innodb_read_only    OFF
innodb_replication_delay    0
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
innodb_rollback_segments    128
innodb_shared_buffer_pool_uses_huge_pages   ON
innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576
innodb_spin_wait_delay  6
innodb_stats_auto_recalc    ON
innodb_stats_method nulls_equal
innodb_stats_on_metadata    OFF
innodb_stats_persistent ON
innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages    20
innodb_stats_sample_pages   8
innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages 8
innodb_strict_mode  OFF
innodb_support_xa   ON
innodb_sync_array_size  1
innodb_sync_spin_loops  30
innodb_table_locks  ON
innodb_thread_concurrency   0
innodb_thread_sleep_delay   10000
innodb_undo_directory   .
innodb_undo_logs    128
innodb_undo_tablespaces 0
innodb_use_native_aio   OFF
innodb_use_sys_malloc   ON
innodb_version  1.2.10
innodb_write_io_threads 4
```

Comment: According to the FAQ here: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/, MyISAM is not supported on Aurora.

Comment: Hi @Yago - May I know your latest on this one? I'm interested in what you ended up doing for this one. I have some plans to ingest large amounts of data into Aurora, and I'm thinking along the lines of ingesting sorted data, split into multiple files and then loading them.

Comment: Hi @big-K! I was able to upload them disabling `unique_checks`, `foreign_keys_check` and `auto_commit`. Also, I removed all the keys (PK and FK) and constraints. I still used the 506 files and it took a while (don't remember the exact time but was about 2 days, if I'm not mistaken) but was faisable.

Answer (score 0):

- Since your data is in PK order, you may as well have both `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `PRIMARY KEY` turned on.
- It *might* help to load each 7M-row chunk into a separate table, then `INSERT .. SELECT` to copy them into the main table.
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for further discussion.  And some important queries.
- For tables that size, FKs may be more trouble than worth.
- Are there any secondary indexes?
- Are you using `LOAD DATA`?  Or loading from a `mysqldump` file?

As for MyISAM...

- If the table will be readonly, then *maybe*.
- The disk space will be 1/3 to 1/2 as much as for InnoDB.
- FKs are *ignored*.
- The PK is kept in a separate BTree, not 'clustered' with the data.  (This helps with some queries, but hurts with others.)
- You would need space for both InnoDB's buffer_pool and MyISAM's key_buffer.
- MyISAM will go away some day.

Change `innodb_log_file_size` to 1G if Aurora will let you.

Comment: Hi, @Rick James! Thanks for the answer. I'm using LOAD DATA FROM S3 command. I noticed that during the first inserts there was no Disk Reads, only Writes, but now the Reads are increasing along with Insert Latency and my writes are dropping. There are some secondary indexes, but I disabled them in the table creation and will build them after the bulk load.

Comment: Would it be worse if I parallelize the LOAD DATA (Execute multiple queries each with a chunk)?

Comment: @YagoCarvalho - If keys are not disabled, it could be thrashing on KEY `idLawSuit10` (`idLawSuit`).

Comment: I used `SET FOREIGN_KEYS_CHECK = 0`

Comment: @YagoCarvalho - A big write operation builds a big undo buffer.  Once that is bigger than the log file size, it has to put stuff elsewhere.

Comment: @YagoCarvalho - How much RAM?

Comment: @YagoCarvalho - Change `innodb_log_file_size` to 1G if Aurora will let you.

Comment: @YagoCarvalho - You disabled _foreign key checks_, as distinct from _keys_.

Comment: Now I have 128GB of RAM. Aurora won't let me increase the `innodb_log_file_size`. About the _key_ disable, is it possible to disable it without dropping the table?

Comment: About the undo buffer, I'm with `autocommit` enabled. Shouldn't it impact on the undo buffer size?

Comment: @YagoCarvalho - `autocommit = ON` is essentially shorthand for putting `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` around each write statement.  If such a statement is a million-row `INSERT`, that is a million rows to prepare to "undo" in case of a crash.

Comment: Oh, I see. But I have the `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` set to 1. In this case the DB should flush the logs after the commit, right? If it's correct, I can't see how this is impacting only now since all my files were this big.

Comment: @YagoCarvalho - Your files are too big.  1K rows at a time is about optimal -- big enough to get 99% of the benefit, small enough not to hit issues with spilling the undo log.  You might even go to 10K.  But not 7M.

Answer (score 0):

I’m dealing with same issue with each file having 100k records. First few files take only 20 seconds to load, but starting on file #4 or 5 I starts to go to 130 seconds or so. This tells me that I’m overwhelming some buffer parameter and starting to page. I’ve fiddled with so many parameters and can’t really tell any improvement. Also tried disabling unique checks and FK with no marked improvements.